# Isn't const supposed to be constant?

Tags: c

Check out this code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

 const int a=7;
 int *p=&a;
 (*p)++;
 printf("*p=%d\np=%u\na=%d\n&a%u",*p,p,a,&a);
 getch();
}
```

The output you get for this is

```
*p=8
p=1245064
a=8
&a1245064
```

How is this possible?? We declared variable a as constant. Doesnt this mean that the location pointed to by a can never be changed during the course of pgm execution??

Comment: This shouldn't compile (it doesn't on Visual C++). What compiler are you using?

Comment: it only gives a warning saying suspicious pointer conversion

Comment: also compiles without errors on gcc 4.4.4, only gives one warning inre discarding qualifiers.

Comment: Since nobody has mentioned it, in C++ that warning would be changed to an error. C++ takes `const` pretty seriously.

Comment: Why are you still using bcc32?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's undefined behavior - in your case it is working as you described, but it could just as well crash the program or cause any other problems. In your case `const` doesn't prevent the compiler from allocating the variable in modifiable memory, so you technically can modify it by obtaining a pointer to that variable and working through the pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Undefined behaviour is not to be relied upon ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Would you really want to use C if it actually prevented that from working?  The fact it works that way is very much in the spirit of the language.

Comment: Haha! That really sums up c doesnt it!

Comment: Yes I would really want to use C if it prevented that from working.  More so than if it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your comment "it only gives a warning saying suspicious pointer conversion" it should be clear enough to deduce that you are doing something illegal.

You are assigning to a `int *` variable a `const int *` value.

The fact that C hasn't any runtime checkings to prevent you from modifying that memory address doesn't imply that it's allowed! (and in fact, the static type system checking is telling you that).

Comment: Not something illegal so much as something questionable.  If it was illegal, compiler should be throwing errors instead of warnings.

Comment: The fact that you can break a rule (or law), doesn't make it less illegal. Usually, a warning in a compiler means that you are doing something wrong, but it's "smart enough" to figure out a way to go on and make it work (sometimes in an undesirable or unexpected manner).

Answer (score 1):

If yours doesn't detect this automatically, just get yourself a decent compiler. E.g clang gives me 4 problems with your code:

```
clang    -c -o test-const.o test-const.c
test-const.c:17:7: warning: initializing 'int const *' discards qualifiers, expected 'int *' [-pedantic]
 int *p=&a;
      ^ ~~
test-const.c:19:20: warning: conversion specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]
 printf("*p=%d\np=%u\na=%d\n&a%u",*p,p,a,&a);
                  ~^                 ~
test-const.c:19:32: warning: conversion specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'int const *' [-Wformat]
 printf("*p=%d\np=%u\na=%d\n&a%u",*p,p,a,&a);
                              ~^         ~~
test-const.c:20:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'getch' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 getch();
 ^
4 diagnostics generated.
```

These are all serious problems.